# Rails: How to get value from different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I generated two scaffolds: **creditcards** and **creditscore**.

- There's a has_many association between users and creditcards.
- There's a has_one association between users and creditscore.

In the creditcards credits.html.erb view, I'm trying to display the current_user's score from the creditscore model.

Here's what I've tried putting in **creditcards_controller.rb**:

```
  def credits
    @creditscores = Creditscore.find_all_by_user_id current_user[:id] if current_user
    @creditscore = current_user.creditscore
  end
```

And in credits.html.erb view:

```
<%= creditscore.score %>
```

Here's the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `creditscore' for #<#<Class:0x00000101a69558>:0x00000101a68680>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only instance variables intialized in the controller is available in the views.

You should use

```
<%= @creditscore.score %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

- Model: Dogs
- Model: Cats
- Controller: Cats

1 - Set your global in Cats controller:
`@dogs = Dogs.all`

2 - Use @dogs in your Cats view: 
`<%= @dogs.cats_hunted %>`